# Firebase google SignIn result is always false?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to register my app using Firebase google Sign In methods. The `googleSignInResult.isSuccess()` returns always false.  I tried googling all possible sites. But couldn't find whats wrong with my code.

```
    googleSignInButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.googleSignInButton);
    googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent googleSignInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(googleSignInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

        }
    });
```

Code for Handling the result

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        Log.d(TAG , "Google signIn" + googleSignInResult.isSuccess() );
        if(googleSignInResult.isSuccess())
        {
            GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
            AuthCredential accountAuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider
                    .getCredential(googleSignInAccount.getIdToken(),null);
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(accountAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }else{

                    }
                }
            });


        }else {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did u enabled in firebase console?

Comment: Yes.I have enabled the firebase console.

Comment: can you post some references to solutions you tried or introduce more code here.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue. The following solved it:

1. Ensure SHA1 configured in Firebase project settings
2. In build.gradle (App) set:

   > apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   in the beginning of the file and

   > apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   >   at the end after dependencies {....}

   Hope this helps